# WP E-commerce Plugin - Store Page changed over night, not sure what caused it

Tags: css

I just released a website for a client, pacayamountaincoffee.com. I woke up this morning and found that the single product areas are very tall now. See here: http://pacayamountaincoffee.com/store

I have not edited the CSS since releasing the site and this just happened overnight.  Would it be a bug from the plugin or something I am not noticing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have:

```
.default_product_display .imagecol {
text-align: right;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
min-height: 50px;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
border: transparent;
}
```

Remove the `height: 100%` and you should be good to go

Comment: Paul, that did the job, thank you so much! Also, I checked the site with IE and everything was fine on launch and now in IE the site is not centered and the secondary A side (widget area) isn't displaying properly and the contact form is all messed up. Is there any way you could look at this?  It looks normal in all other browsers.

Comment: Matt, I just saw this message. I took a look at the site and it looks like your got everything sorted out in IE.

Comment: Hi Paul, I did. Thank you very much for your help! Be well.